# How to wrap a consecutive range of integers?

Tags: math, integer

What is the shortest possible calculation `f(i, n, len, offset)` that wraps a range of integers starting from `n` (>=0) with length `len`, given a certain `offset`?

```
i   offset 0  offset 1  offset 2  offset 15
10  -> 10     -> 15     -> 14     -> 13
11  -> 11     -> 10     -> 15     -> 14
12  -> 12     -> 11     -> 10     -> 11
13  -> 13     -> 12     -> 11     -> 10
14  -> 14     -> 13     -> 12     -> 11
15  -> 15     -> 14     -> 13     -> 12
```

So `f(10, 10, 5, 1) = 15`, `f(15, 10, 5, 1) = 14` and `f(10, 10, 5, 2) = 14`.

Bonus karma for negative numbers or negative offsets or ranges that cross 0.

Comment: Seems like "i" isn't used or necessary? What do you mean by "wrap" and what is the role of "offset" in this? Please, explain better.

Comment: @Dimitre I want an arbitrary range of consecutive integers, say, `1..15` that wraps for addition and subtraction (adding 2 to 14 should return 1). The offset is used to indicate that the range does not necessarily start at 1. Weekdays are such an example. You could define Sunday=1 and Saturday=7, but the week does not neccesarily *start* on Sunday, but for some regions on Monday (=2). I wanted to have a generic answer nevertheless.

Comment: So, by wraps" you mean the last integer of the interval -- is this correct? Then the question still remains for `i` -- what is its meaning?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "shortest possible", but this seems to work:

```
f(int n, int base, int len, int offset)
{ int r = n - offset;
  if (r < base)
    r += len;
  return r;
}
```

It does require adding the `base` argument, though, because otherwise you have no idea where `n` is with respect to the range (e.g. is 15 at the bottom of the 15-20 range or the top of 10-15?). So your examples would become `f(10, 10, 6, 1)`, `f(15, 10, 6, 1)`, etc...

Haven't checked whether that works for negative numbers and/or ranges spanning 0, and it also fails if `offset > len`, but that can be worked around by adding `offset %= len` to normalize the input parameters.

Comment: Well, in `f(10, 5, 0)` the `10` would be the base and `10 + 5` would be the top of the range?

Comment: But if you interpret `10` and `5` as defining the range, what is the number that you want to calculate the offset for? Or were you looking for a loop that prints the offset for all the numbers in the range? If so, I guess I mis-read the question - the `f()` I gave will calculate the offset value for a `n` in the range from `base` to `base + len`. You could call `f()` in a loop to get all the remapped values in the range.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Of course I need a numer to calculate the offset for.

Comment: As to "shortest possible" - I was trying to create a `mod` one-liner but failed.